# Pygame grey screen, not loading any visuals

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

I've just started working with pygame and all the sample (getting started) code I have run, gives me a blank screen. Including the space invaders example which play the sound but shows only the grey blank screen as shown below. 
[grey blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5NRh.png)

I am getting no errors in my terminal, I have tried with both python3 and python2.7. I have also tried with many different scripts but still I am getting the grey blank screen. Below is an example script I have tried to run. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

yellow = (255,255,0) # RGB color tuple

# initialize screen
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((350, 250))
pygame.display.set_caption('Basic Pygame program')

# fill background
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill(yellow)

# display some text
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text = font.render("Hello from Monty PyGame", 1, (10, 10, 10))
textpos = text.get_rect()
textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
background.blit(text, textpos)

# blit everything to the screen
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()

# event loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: It's possible that your operating system is claiming that it is capable of double-buffering, but it actually can't. Unlikely, but just throwing it out there. Try changing the settings of the `set_mode` call.

Comment: no, changing the setting of the set_mode call did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw the background and update the display in the application loop rather than the event loop:

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
    
    # INDENTATION
     
    #<--|
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been banging my head against the wall for years on this one!